# How to set readonly attribute of a tinymce editor false?

Tags: tinymce, text-editor

I have a tinymce editor on a textarea of my page. I am initializing it in READONLY mode by setting readonly attribute as true. Please refer init below:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "exact",
    elements : "p_desc",
    debug : false,
    nowrap : false,
    cleanup_on_startup : true,
    fix_nesting : true,
    readonly : true,
    force_br_newlines : true,
    force_p_newlines : false,
    gecko_spellcheck : true,
    forced_root_block : '' ,
...
    setup : function(ed) {
            ed.onKeyUp.add(function(ed) {
                textCounter('p_desc','Charcount',4000);
            });}
});
```

Now depending upon the value of a hidden input field on the same page, i am enabling edit using tinyMCE.get('p_desc').getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', true);

The editor starts working in editable mode but the onKeyUp event defined in setup is still not working.

Someone please help.

Comment: Try intialising with readonly mode off, and putting it in RO mode afterwards.

Comment: David, doing what you said, doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
tinyMCE.init({
    readonly : true,
...
    setup : function(ed) {
            if (!ed.getParam('readonly')) ed.onKeyUp.add(function(ed) {
                textCounter('p_desc','Charcount',4000);
            });}
});
```

Comment: Thariama, i want this event to work irrespective of the value of readonly attribute.

Comment: hmm, might get difficult here, looks like a bug to me

Comment: you are using which version of tinymce?